# How do I add my view engine(ejs) to a combination of express and web pack dev server?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I am trying to integrate ejs to a express and web pack dev server project, and I am unable to do so because even though I am passing my variables, they are loading like this

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  ReferenceError: name is not defined

  - index.ejs:102 ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/templates/views/index.ejs.module.exports
    C:/Users/arora/OneDrive/Documents/Rishab/Projects/Webpress/src/templates/views/index.ejs:102:11

  - index.js:284 
    [Webpress]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:284:18

  - task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5
```

This [Error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lrG2pQphuaXN84oQvBBJnItV7lzZTIIp/view?usp=sharing) is in the console. Please help, here is the [code link](https://github.com/Gizmo-Rishab/Webpress). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When webpack compiles your `ejs` to HTML it has no `local` variables passed to the template, and so you get this error. If you know the variables in advance you can likely pass these as options in webpack --- see `ejs-html-loader`.

If you're want to still use variables passed to the page via ejs you will want to use a separate "template" `ejs` file that is really barebones --- just to pass data into `<script>`.

If you want to continue passing variables into your "html" of the page you will need to use some sort of ejs loader keep the `ejs` output in some fashion, which might limit your options on what loaders you can use for other webpack optimizations.